# Reflections not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, lightbox, nyromodal

I'm using the latest version (v1.6.2) of [nyromodal lightbox](http://nyromodal.nyrodev.com/):

```
jQuery.nyroModalSettings({title:'Manual Title'});
```

It won't reflect any title and the lightbox title remains empty.  I also tried:

```
jQuery.nyroModalManual({
  title:'Manual Title'
});
```

But nothing reflects.  How can I get the reflection working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The settings of nyromodal says it should work using `title: 'your title'`.

But alternatively you can set the `title` attribute of html element and nyromodal will pick it up.

```
<p><a href="img/img2.jpg" class="nyroModal" title="3rd Street Promenade">Image</a></p>
```

Comment: thanxs for ur reply i need to enter manually so that i did as above i mentioned and jus cleared the cache it works :)

Answer (score 1):

Try changing `$.fn.nyroModal.settings` or set the `a` tag  title attribute. The only reason it may not work is you have empty title attribute in your link or its broken in `manual` call

Comment: thanxs i did same script above i mentioned and cleared the cache its works fine